# Data dd-mm-yyyy openpyxl python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Quero que minha váriavel retorne a data em `dd-mm-yyyy`, porém ela está retornando `yyyy-mm-dd`. Já tentei de tudo mais não consegui o resultado que queria.

Meu código de teste é esse:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xlsx = "..\Documents\Programação\RPA\Jupyter\Projeto ISS - Fiscal\Teste.xlsx"
excel = load_workbook(filename=xlsx)

sheet = excel['Plan1']


for linha in range(2, len(sheet['A']) + 1):

    NrNf = sheet['A%s' % linha].value
    SerieNf = sheet['B%s' % linha].value
    Atividade = sheet['C%s' % linha].value
    DtEmis = sheet['D%s' % linha].value
```

Com base nisso, como posso fazer um print da minha váriavel `DtEmis` retornar a data como `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, acabei levando a tarde de muita dor de cabeça, mais aqui vai a resposta.
A variável DtEmit é um valor imutável, não podendo ser alterado. Para isso, foi necessário importar o Datetime, e criar uma classe própria para ele.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

xlsx = "..\Documents\Programação\RPA\Jupyter\Projeto ISS -Fiscal\Teste.xlsx"
excel = load_workbook(filename=xlsx)

sheet = excel['Plan1']


for linha in range(2, len(sheet['A']) + 1):

    NrNf = sheet['A%s' % linha].value
    SerieNf = sheet['B%s' % linha].value
    Atividade = sheet['C%s' % linha].value
    DtEmis = sheet['D%s' % linha].value
 
x = datetime.strftime(DtEmis, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Em suma, a variável x desempenhará o papel de fazer a conversão para String, e me entregará o valor que estou requerendo (Data em formato dd-MM-yyyy).

Obrigado.

Fonte: https://appdividend.com/2022/03/22/how-to-convert-datetime-to-string-in-python/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502726/converting-date-between-dd-mm-yyyy-and-yyyy-mm-dd